# Resetting prototypes in Javascript. Why does it destroy the prototype inheritance chain?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have this code:

```
function PrintStuff(docs) {
  this.docs = docs;
}

PrintStuff.prototype.print = function() {
  console.log(this.docs)
}

var printer = new PrintStuff("Hello World");
printer.print()
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(printer))
console.log(PrintStuff.prototype)
console.log(printer instanceof(PrintStuff))
//true

PrintStuff.prototype = {}
console.log(printer instanceof(PrintStuff))
//false
```

1. What kind of method is instanceof? Why isn't it being called on the object?
2. Why does setting the prototype of PrintStuff destroy the inheritance chain for the printer object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instanceof is JavaScript operator - it checks whether a function (constructor)'s prototype object exists in the prototype chain of the object being checked.

When you create an object using **new**, javascript sets the object's internal prototype to link to the new'd function's prototype object. When you change the new'd function to have a different prototype object, the original created object is still linked to the new'd function's original prototype object.

(In Chrome), you can access the object's internal prototype link, and therefore reverse it by doing `PrintStuff.prototype = printer.__proto__`, if that gives you a better understanding of what's happening.

**What do you mean by "reverse it"?**

Initially, when you create the PrintStuff function, the PrintStuff object is linked to its prototype like so:

```
[PrintStuff] --- prototype ---> [PrintStuffPrototype]
```

When you do this: `PrintStuff.prototype = {}` you get:

```
[PrintStuff] -link lost- [PrintStuffPrototype]
       `.
         `---- prototype ---> {}
```

The PrintStuffPrototype object is hanging in memory. Reversing it means re-linking the original PrintStuffPrototype to the PrintStuff function.

Comment: Awesome, but what do you mean by "reverse it"?

Comment: @Jwan622 refer to my edit

Answer (score 2):

1. `instanceof` is an operator, not a method. What you wrote was like `1 +(2)`.
2. `PrintStuff.prototype` is not the prototype *of* `PrintStuff`; it is the prototype *for* the objects created by `PrintStuff` constructor. When you replace it, any objects created after that will no longer have `.print` method. `printer` still does, as it still has the old prototype.
3. (1+2, really): As MDN says, The instanceof operator tests whether an object (`printer`) has in its prototype chain (old `PrintStuff.prototype`) the prototype property of a constructor (new `PrintStuff.prototype`, or `{}`)." As the two are clearly different, `instanceof` returns `false`.